# Boost::Multiindex vs string indexed boost::unordered_map

Tags: c++, boost, multidimensional-array, boost-multi-index

I need a container of unique elements to be accessed with a triplet of int, and each int can be over 1.000.000.000.

(Only few of these elements will be actually filled, and actually these elements are boost::unordered_map themselves).

Is it faster to have a multiindex array like boost::multiindex (or maybe something else I don't know) or just a boost::unordered_map with a composed string as a key ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-index isn't what you want, you seem to want a single index whose type is a triple. (Unless you actually do want three independent indexes; if I misunderstood, leave a comment.)

Don't use strings, heavens no. Just use the triple as a key:

```
typedef std::tuple<int, int, int> key_type;
```

If you use an `std::map<key_type, T>`, you get logarithmic lookup, which may be sufficient, and I think you don't even have to do any more work (not sure if lexicographic comparison is defined by default for tuples).

If you want to use an `std::unordered_map<key_type, T>` (or the boost version), you have to define a hash function. Boost already has one for tuples, I think, but C++11 doesn't; but it's very easy to implement yourself based on `hash_combine()` which you can just crop out off the Boost code.

Comment: I do think that `std::tuple` has a lexicographic `operator<` built-in... as long as *all* the types you pass in do, of course.

Comment: @Matthieu: Cheers, good to know. St0rM: If you don't have tuples, (check also `<tr1/tuple>` or `<boost/tuple>` if you don't have `<tuple>`), then you could make one up yourself, or use `pair<pair<int,int>,int>`...

Comment: In fact, it seems boost::tuple is better, even if now I have to bonk my head a little to discover how it works. Thanks

Comment: It works like a pair, just with more elements, and accessing elements uses some template syntax. The advantage of the boost tuple is that you should be able to use it in an unordered map straight out of the box.

Comment: In fact, it needs a hash function to be defined for your tuple, and it's a bit tricky because you have to remember that tuple is under boost::tuples and not under boost. So it's something like:

`namespace boost {
 namespace tuples {
  std::size_t hash_value(key_type const& e) {
   std::size_t seed = 0;
    boost::hash_combine( seed, e.get<0>() );
    boost::hash_combine( seed, e.get<1>() );
    boost::hash_combine( seed, e.get<2>() );
   return seed;
  }
 }
}`

...but it's pretty easy anyway :-)

Comment: @St0rM: Oh OK - well, glad you figured it out. I thought that Boost defines hashes for all sorts of stuff, but tuples don't seem to be among them. With variadic templates you could write a generic implementation, but if you only need the triple, this'll do fine.

Comment: @Kerrek: Maybe you want to update your answer with it... Up to you. And thank you again, you spared me a lot of headaches :-)